# Gitlab CI - test project hangs on DbConnection.CreateCommand()

Tags: c#, sql-server, docker, .net-core, gitlab

I just started using docker and wanted to also use gitlab-ci for builds and tests. After painfully long and numerous attempts I finally managed to prep my images and gitlab-ci.yml. My project consists of WebApi, database project and test project.
My current flow is (using docker/compose and dind in gitlab-ci):

1. Build stage:

   - build webapi and load it to container registry
   - build database and load it to container registry (image mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest)
2. Test stage:

   - run docker-compose on compose file that prepares testing:

     - start database container from image in container registry build in build stage
     - build test project and start the container
   - docer execute on test container "dotnet test 'Tests.csproj'"

One more important piece of information - the test project is using [Respawn](https://github.com/jbogard/respawn) to reset the database to clean state for integration tests. It basically goes through the object graph and deletes data before each tests (also handles nicely the relationships). For sql server it uses SqlConnection (abstracted to DbConnection in later stages of the code) to connect to the database.

If I run this on my local machine (manually create the database image and then run docker-compose from 2a, and manually run `docker-compose -f Tests/docker-compose.ci.yml -p dockercomposeForTests --no-ansi up -d`) the tests are running fine.

However from gitlab.com, tests are hanging on the Respawn. They stop exactly on DbConnection.CreateCommand(). At this stage it seems to me, that there is some kind of a problem either in my setup or in the container, but afters days of trying to resolve this issue, I do not have any more ideas.

I know the database is up and the tests are connecting to it. First, Respawn is opening a working connection. Second, I also have a Hangfire starting and connecting to exactly the same database (uses the same connection string as Respawn), and hangfire is reporting connectivity (at first I had some problems with it but I left it because it helps me to diagnose if connection is alive and working; at some point I will probably get rid of it so it won't slow down the tests).

Comment: Are you sure it's hanging on DbConnection.CreateCommand()? That doesn't do any network access.

Comment: So what I did, I put a number of Log.Debug. Eventually I narrowed it to the DbConnection.CreateConnection() statement (Log.Debug before was shown, the Log.Debug after does not show until 1hr timeout and stage cancellation). At the same time, if I turn off Respawn, all tests are passing (failing due to db not being cleaned up, but still running until the end without hanging).

Comment: Correct. In all honesty, I am using Jimmy Bogard's Respawn library, his library is using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient. To be exact the connection is set to new SqlConnection(nameOrConnectionString), then in another function (where it hangs) a connection as System.Data.Common.DbConnection is requested to create connection.CreateCommand(). This is where everything stops. And I agree, I do not understand what is happening and that is why I asked the question. And in my local containers it works. I am truly baffled.